# how to force tag page layout to use same as search layout?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, templates, template-hierarchy

I have remarked that when clicking on a tag I have a list of posts displayed differently that when I use search box.

How to force tag page layout to use same as search layout for any template ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell WordPress to use the `search.php` template whenever viewing tags by using the [`template_include`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include). It works like this:

```
function wpse_240429() {

    // IF we're planning on loading a tag template
    if( is_tag() ) {

        // Try to locate the search.php template
        $search_template = locate_template( 'search.php' );

        // If the search template exists
        if( ! empty( $search_template ) ) {

            // Use search.php for display purposes
            return $search_template ;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'template_include', 'wpse_240429' );
```

You shouldn't have to mess with things like `pre_get_posts` as the query should already be pulled.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png), you will see that the search page has a different template than the archive page. When there is no `search.php` search results will be shown using `index.php`.

From your question I gather you want to show search results using `archive.php` or perhaps even `tag.php`. This is easily achieved by making your own one line `search.php` with [`get_template_part`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/):

```
<?php get_template_part('archive.php');
```

Comment: I want the other way round: tag template to use search template

Comment: Well, then apply the solution the other way around